# Insert with Select using predefined data for columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-insert

i have a table called "A" with a single column called "height" lets say.

this column has 20 values.

my other table B has Height, ID and display order

Now i want to put in Height from table A but i also want to make sure the ID is always "1" and display order is always "0"

so far...

```
INSERT
INTO [B]
(Height, ID,DisplayOrder)
SELECT
  [Height]    
  FROM [A]
  where [Height] is not null
  group by [Height]
```

Cant for the life of me remember how to do this, buggin me as i know its a simple solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `insert . . . select` syntax:

```
insert into B(height, ID, DisplayOrder)
    select A.Height, 1, 0
    from A;
```

If there are duplicates in `A` and you only want one inserted, then use `group by` or `distinct`:

```
insert into B(height, ID, DisplayOrder)
    select distinct A.Height, 1, 0
    from A;
```

Comment: nice! totally forgot i can explicitly use the value in the select, massive derp on my side (been a looong day) many thanks Gordon Linoff